# Сравнить 2 Excel файла с одинаковым количеством столбцов, но разным количеством строк

Tags: python, pandas, сравнение, анализ

Есть 2 файла. Их нужно сравнить. Известно, что строки могут меняться местами, количество строк может увеличиваться (могут появляться новые позиции). Нужно подсвечивать/выводить те значения, которые поменялись. Желательно старые значения тоже выводить.
Я пробовала так:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('2.xlsx')
df1 = df1[15:]

df1['Unnamed: 1'].loc[15]='Index'
for n in range(4, df1.shape[1],2):
    df1['Unnamed: %s'%n].loc[15]=df1['Unnamed: %s'%(n-1)].loc[15]
df1.columns = df1.loc[15:16].fillna('').apply(' '.join).str.strip()
df1 = df1[2:]

df1.reset_index(drop=True).head()
#df1 = df1.set_index('Index')

df2 = df2[15:]
df2['Unnamed: 1'].loc[15]='Index'
for n in range(4, df2.shape[1],2):
    df2['Unnamed: %s'%n].loc[15]=df2['Unnamed: %s'%(n-1)].loc[15]
df2.columns = df2.loc[15:16].fillna('').apply(' '.join).str.strip()
df2 = df2[2:]

df2.reset_index(drop=True).head()
#df2 = df2.set_index('Index') 
difference = df2[df1!=df2]

difference.fillna(' ')
```

Если я устанавливаю индексом столбец "Index" , то программа ломается при замене местами строк и вообще не работате, когда я добавляю новые строки.
Если же я не устанавлиываю столбец "Index" , то при смене строк местами она подсвечивает все две строки.
То есть, предположим, что есть 2 таблицы: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] и [image: введите сюда описание изображения] нужно получить: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Файлы располагаются по ссылкам:

[файл1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lprDyfSISL-Dtk-lZFKcOOCxVDU3ni5qBLkFEgS9fY0/edit#gid=1959535501)

[файл2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z1OunDucKmKpPtWqUb1bEG0Rj4ZOC-qZtTNKBn3G7MY/edit#gid=1796031991)

Comment: [здесь есть несколько решений...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/compare-two-dataframes-and-output-their-differences-side-by-side)

Comment: @MaxU спасибо посмотрю

Comment: Главное определиться - как вы вообще сопоставляете строки. Есть ли в них уникальные идентификаторы, по которым их можно сопоставить.

Comment: @CrazyElf айди - это столбец Индекс, в котором в строков формате перечислены проекты

Comment: @MaxU все решения по ссылке, основаны на том, что файлы идентичны по размеру, а у меня добавляются строки

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе [mcve] и результат который вы хотите получить?

Comment: @MaxU привела на примере двух таблиц

Comment: этот вопрос тянет на небольшой проект для фрилансера... ;)

Comment: @strawdog  может сможете дать наметки на решение задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот смотрите: судя по вашим файлам, первый значимый уникальный столбец у вас будет идти под номером 2 - его и нужно делать индексом. Затем сравнивать по строками датафреймы - вы увидите строки, которые не совпадают. Например, так:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx', skiprows=18)
df2 = pd.read_excel('2.xlsx', skiprows=18)
df1=df1.set_index(2)
df2=df2.set_index(2)

for i in df1.index:
    if not (df1.loc[i].equals(df2.loc[i])):
        print(f"df1:{df1.loc[[i]]}, \ndf2{df2.loc[[i]]}")
        print("===")
```

вы получите попарно несовпадающие строки из обоих фреймов:

```
df1:                                                 1  3    4.1    4.2     4.3     4.4   4.5    4.6     4.7      4.8 5.1   5.2 5.3 5.4 6.1     6.2 6.3   6.4 6.5 6.6 7.1 7.2   8.1   8.2     9.1    9.2     9.3     9.4
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ВСЕГО по инвестиционной программе, в том числе:  0  Г  48.48  57.94  418.89  488.76  49.7  60.58  108.89  163.535  нд  42.6  нд  18  нд  1.2754  нд  0.55  нд  нд  нд  нд  4.94  3.27  305.23  163.4  367.39  341.17, 
df2                                                 1  3    4.1    4.2     4.3     4.4   4.5    4.6     4.7      4.8 5.1   5.2 5.3 5.4 6.1     6.2 6.3   6.4 6.5 6.6 7.1 7.2   8.1   8.2     9.1    9.2     9.3     9.4
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ВСЕГО по инвестиционной программе, в том числе:  0  Г  50.14  57.94  418.89  488.76  49.7  60.58  108.89  163.535  нд  42.6  нд  18  нд  1.2754  нд  0.55  нд  нд  нд  нд  4.94  3.27  305.23  163.4  367.39  341.17
===
df1:                                        1  3    4.1   4.2    4.3   4.4   4.5    4.6     4.7      4.8 5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4 6.1 6.2 6.3 6.4 6.5 6.6 7.1 7.2 8.1 8.2 9.1 9.2 9.3 9.4
2                                                                                                                                                                           
Технологическое присоединение, всего  0.1  Г  44.36  48.4  12.57  0.16  40.1  49.73  108.89  138.245  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд, 
df2                                        1  3    4.1   4.2    4.3   4.4   4.5    4.6     4.7      4.8 5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4 6.1 6.2 6.3 6.4 6.5 6.6 7.1 7.2 8.1 8.2 9.1 9.2 9.3 9.4
2                                                                                                                                                                           
Технологическое присоединение, всего  0.1  Г  47.38  48.4  12.57  0.16  40.1  49.73  108.89  138.245  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд  нд
===
```

и уже со значениями в этих строках можете работать.

Однако, нужно иметь в виду, что здесь еще не учитывается вариант, когда количество строк во фреймах не совпадает.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромнейшее, а когда строки не совпадают по размерам- я добавляю тот же самый индекс и заполняю его None.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('2.xlsx')
df1 = df1[15:]




df1['Unnamed: 1'].loc[15]='Index'
df1['Unnamed: 2'].loc[15]='Index 2'
df1['Unnamed: 0'].loc[15]='Index 3'
for n in range(4, df1.shape[1],2):
    df1['Unnamed: %s'%n].loc[15]=df1['Unnamed: %s'%(n-1)].loc[15]
df1.columns = df1.loc[15:16].fillna('').apply(' '.join).str.strip()
df1 = df1[2:]

df1.reset_index(drop=True).head()
df1 = df1.set_index('Index')




df2 = df2[15:]
df2['Unnamed: 1'].loc[15]='Index'
df2['Unnamed: 2'].loc[15]='Index 2'
df2['Unnamed: 0'].loc[15]='Index 3'
for n in range(4, df2.shape[1],2):
    df2['Unnamed: %s'%n].loc[15]=df2['Unnamed: %s'%(n-1)].loc[15]
df2.columns = df2.loc[15:16].fillna('').apply(' '.join).str.strip()
df2 = df2[2:]


df2.reset_index(drop=True).head()
df2 = df2.set_index('Index')

for ind in df2.index:
    if ind not in df1.index:
        df1.loc[ind] = [np.nan] * df1.shape[1]
    

df1.to_excel('1a.xlsx')
df2.to_excel('2a.xlsx')


df1 = pd.read_excel('1a.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('2a.xlsx')

df1 = df1.drop([0])
df2 = df2.drop([0])

df0 = df2.set_index('Index')

df1 = df1.sort_values(['Index'])
df1 = df1.set_index('Index')


df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['Index'])
df2 = df2.set_index('Index')

df_all = pd.concat([df1, df2],axis='columns', keys=['First', 'Second'], sort=False)
df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df1.columns[1:]]

# df_final = df_final.reindex(df0.index)
# df_final = df_final.reindex(list(df0.index))
df_final = df_final.reset_index()

# df_final = df_final.sort_values(by = 'Index', key = df0.index)

def highlight_diff(data, color='yellow'):
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    other = data.xs('First', axis='columns', level=-1)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other, level=0), attr, ''),
                        index=data.index, columns=data.columns)



# df_final['tosort'] = df0.index
# df_final = df_final.sort_values('tosort')

df_final = df_final.style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=None)
# df_final = df_final.set_index("Index")
# df_final = df_final.reindex(df0.index)
df_final
```

Осталась одна проблемка - отсортировать фрейм по столбцу Index, как в первоначальном файле

Comment: Вам в таком случае нужно попробовать сделать так: вместо `df=df.set_index(2)` (для обоих фреймов) сделать `df = df.reset_index().set_index(2)`. А затем, после всех манипуляций, вернуть индекс обратно: `df = df.reset_index().set_index("index")`.